# changing expressions to bold face in ggplot2 while preserving its size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display an expression in a `ggplot2` plot axis, where I want to simultaneously change both the `size` and `face` for the axis test:

Using `ggplot2::element_text`, I can change `size`, but not `face`.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = parse(text = "widehat(mu)=='6'"),
    breaks = 6
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(face = "bold", size = 12))
```

[image]

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281897/ggplot2-font-style-in-label-expression), I can wrap the expression in `bold`, which partly works (note that only `6` is in bold, and not italic mu) but then the text `size` doesn't change:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = parse(text = "bold(widehat(mu)=='6')"),
    breaks = 6
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.text.x = ggplot2::element_text(face = "bold", size = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Is there any way to do this in `ggplot2` itself? Or one will have to use something like `ggtext`?

Comment: Is `.top` in the 2nd `axis.text.x` a typo? Remove it and it works.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the dumb mistake :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to make the font size vary as requested.
The `.top` in the second plot's `theme` seems to be a typo, remove it and the font becomes bigger.
And instead of `parse`, use `expression` for plotmath.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = expression(bold(widehat(mu) == '6')),
    breaks = 6
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12))
```

[image]

Here is another one, with the axis label even bigger.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = expression(bold(widehat(mu) == '6')),
    breaks = 6
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 24))
```

[image]